# Wrong annotation text location on basemap

Tags: annotations, matplotlib-basemap, scatter

I try to annotate sampling position name on each scatter sample location based on mercator projection. I used sampling position as annotation location with map projection coordinate. But placed annotation location is wrong position on map.
Ex. When I annotate some position in pacific ocean, annotate text placed on Japan inland.

My map is below.
[image]

Here is my code.

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.inset_locator import inset_axes
from matplotlib.patches import Polygon
# create new figure, axes instances.
fig=plt.figure()
ax=fig.add_axes([0.1,0.1,0.8,0.8])
# setup mercator map projection.
m = Basemap(llcrnrlon=120.,llcrnrlat=10.,urcrnrlon=150.,urcrnrlat=44.,\
        rsphere=(6378137.00,6356752.3142),\
        resolution='l',projection='merc',\
        lat_0=20.,lon_0=135.,lat_ts=25)
# nylat, nylon are lat/lon of Guam
nylat = 14; nylon = 140
# lonlat, lonlon are lat/lon of Busan.
lonlat = 35; lonlon = 128

# Draw Background Map
m.bluemarble()
m.drawgreatcircle(nylon,nylat,lonlon,lonlat,linewidth=2,color='b')
m.drawcoastlines()
m.fillcontinents()
# draw parallels
m.drawparallels(np.arange(10,50,10),labels=[1,1,0,1])
# draw meridians
m.drawmeridians(np.arange(120,155,10),labels=[1,1,0,1])
#m.drawmapscale(129, 15, 131, 16, 500, barstyle='fancy') drawing map scale
m.ax = ax
# Draw your dataset
lons = [130, 131, 132, 133]
lats = [21, 22, 23, 24]
Annotes = ['Sample #1', '2', '3', '4']
x, y = m(lons, lats)
#m.scatter(x1,y1,s=sizes,c=cols,marker="o",cmap=cm.cool,alpha=0.7)
m.scatter(x, y, s= 20, marker='*',color='y',alpha=0.7)
plt.annotate(Annotes[0], xy=(1110450, 1147253),xycoords='data',
            xytext=(1110450, 1147253),textcoords='data',
            arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="->")
            )
ax.set_title('Cruise line from Guam to Busan')
plt.show()
```

Thanks in advance. Any comments welcome!

Comment: Can you post your figure? I tried your code without `m.marble()`, the annotate text is not in Japan inland. [Link](http://i.stack.imgur.com/IFUyf.png)

Comment: Thank you for your interesting. I edit my original post with my map. Even though except bluemarble(), I got wrong location of annotation text.